# How to add Google sheet data to another Google sheet using appscript I want to add data from one sheet to another sheet using app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Google sheet data from one sheet to another using appscript

I want display on another spreadsheet using appscript
I want to add rows and columns data from one sheet to another using appscript .
Answer it in right`your text` way no error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Copy data from  one spreadsheet to another

```
function copydata() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(gobj.globals.test1id);//replace with id
  const sh1 = ss1.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const vs1 = sh1.getDataRange().getValues()
  const ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(gobj.globals.test2id);//replace with id
  const sh2 = ss2.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  sh2.clearContents();
  sh2.getRange(1,1,vs1.length,vs1[0].length).setValues(vs1);
}
```